# How to convert javascript object into a json string in IE8 compatability mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer-8, stringify

I have an application that runs inside of a viewer that forces the app to run in IE8 compatability mode. I understand IE 8 is not longer supported by Microsoft and it is a very bad browser, but it is a limitation that I have to deal with since I have no control over my Viewer. I am trying to convert an object into json string.

Here is what I have done so far. First, I create JavaScript object like this

```
   var records = {};

   records['123'] = {};
   records['456'] = {};

   records['123']['rec_id'] = 4456;
   records['123']['created_at'] = getCurrentTime();
   records['123']['assigned_at'] = getCurrentTime();
   records['123']['sys_id'] = 1745;

   records['456']['rec_id'] = 4456;
   records['456']['created_at'] = getCurrentTime();
   records['456']['assigned_at'] = getCurrentTime();
   records['456']['sys_id'] = 1745;


   $.each(records, function(callID, record){

            record['campaign_id'] = '1';
            record['offset'] = getCurrentOffset();
            record['attempt'] = '7';
            record['phone'] = '800-123-4567';
            record['identity'] = 123;
            record['code'] = 'Some Code';
            record['notes'] = 'Some notes';
            record['completed_by'] = 'Mike A';
            record['name'] = 'Mike A';

            record['completed_at'] = getCurrentTime();

   });
```

Now, I want to convert my records object into json string.

In modern browsers I can use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert the object with no problem. However, `JSON.stringify()` does not work in IE 8 compatability mode.

I found alternative solution to convert the object into json string [jQuery JSON plugin](https://github.com/Krinkle/jquery-json)

I tried to convert my object using [jQuery JSON plugin](https://github.com/Krinkle/jquery-json)  like so

```
$.toJSON(records);
```

But, that is giving me the following error

```
Line: 116 
Error: Invalid procedure call or argument
URL: copy of the code in this URL https://github.com/Krinkle/jquery-json/blob/master/src/jquery.json.js
```

How can I convert my object into JSON string? am I defining my object incorrectly or is there something else that I need to do to get the object converted?

Comment: Use this, https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js then use `JSON.stringify` like normal.

Comment: IE 8 isn't *that* bad a browser, it's just old.

Comment: @Paulpro Thank you or the tip. I included this file into my app `https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js` Then when I try to using JSON.stringify I get an error "Invalid procedure call or argument" Line 314 of the json2.js file. Is the issue with my object and the way I construct it?