# How to load JSON feature in Javascript for IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to load JSON feature in JavaScript for IE8 in a comparability mode.

I was [advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881010/how-to-convert-javascript-object-into-a-json-string-in-ie8-compatability-mode) to use [douglascrockford/JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to get JSON loaded in obsolete browsers.

Here is what I have done. I added a new file in my resources folder and called it `json2.js` Then from the JSON-js project I copied the `json2.js` file content and pasted it into my `json2.js` file and included the file `resources/json2.js` into my app.

Now, I am trying to use `JSON.stringify` to convert an object into json string which is giving me the following error

But when I use `JSON.stringify(records)` in IE8 under compatibility mode I get this error

```
Line: 314
Char: 21
Error: Invalid procedure call or argument
Code: 0
```

Here is what I have done

HTML Markup

```
<div id="d">Click Here</div>
<div id="s"></div>
```

Javascript code

```
var records = {};


$(function(e){

   records['123'] = {};
   records['456'] = {};

   records['123']['rec_id'] = 4456;
   records['123']['created_at'] = '';
   records['123']['assigned_at'] = '';
   records['123']['sys_id'] = 1745;

   records['456']['rec_id'] = 4456;
   records['456']['created_at'] = '';
   records['456']['assigned_at'] = '';
   records['456']['sys_id'] = 1745;


   $.each(records, function(callID, record){

            record['campaign_id'] = '1';
            record['offset'] = 123;
            record['attempt'] = '7';
            record['phone'] = '800-123-4567';
            record['identity'] = 123;
            record['code'] = 'Some Code';
            record['notes'] = 'Some notes';
            record['completed_by'] = 'Mike A';
            record['name'] = null;

            record['completed_at'] = "";

   });


   $('#d').click(function(e){
        $('#s').text(  JSON.stringify(records)  );
   });

});
```

the above code can be found in the following jFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4632wf5n/

What can I do to convert my object into json string in IE8 with comparability mode?

Comment: Given you are using jQuery, why not use its JSON methods rather than including json2.js as well?

Comment: How would I convert the object using jQuery and not use `JSON.stringify()`? I don't think there is such a thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904269/convert-object-to-json-string

Comment: Sorry, I thought jQuery had an equivalent method, but it looks like I was mistaken. JQuery *does* have a $.parseJSON() method, but obviously that's the opposite of what you're doing.

Comment: Which compatibilty-mode? Your code works without an error for me, even in IE8 with compatibility-mode IE5

Answer (score 0):

Although according to [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON), `JSON.stringify` is supported in *IE8*, in case if it's not, then you can use the **polyfill** (i.e. if it's not supported by browser, then use custom implementation). If Douglas JSON.js is not working then, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) also provides a code for the polyfill, and I have copied that here. Just insert it before any other scripts, and JSON.stringify would work in IE6+ browsers where it's not supported.

```
if (!window.JSON) {
  window.JSON = {
    parse: function(sJSON) { return eval('(' + sJSON + ')'); },
    stringify: (function () {
      var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
      var isArray = Array.isArray || function (a) { return toString.call(a) === '[object Array]'; };
      var escMap = {'"': '\\"', '\\': '\\\\', '\b': '\\b', '\f': '\\f', '\n': '\\n', '\r': '\\r', '\t': '\\t'};
      var escFunc = function (m) { return escMap[m] || '\\u' + (m.charCodeAt(0) + 0x10000).toString(16).substr(1); };
      var escRE = /[\\"\u0000-\u001F\u2028\u2029]/g;
      return function stringify(value) {
        if (value == null) {
          return 'null';
        } else if (typeof value === 'number') {
          return isFinite(value) ? value.toString() : 'null';
        } else if (typeof value === 'boolean') {
          return value.toString();
        } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
          if (typeof value.toJSON === 'function') {
            return stringify(value.toJSON());
          } else if (isArray(value)) {
            var res = '[';
            for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
              res += (i ? ', ' : '') + stringify(value[i]);
            return res + ']';
          } else if (toString.call(value) === '[object Object]') {
            var tmp = [];
            for (var k in value) {
              if (value.hasOwnProperty(k))
                tmp.push(stringify(k) + ': ' + stringify(value[k]));
            }
            return '{' + tmp.join(', ') + '}';
          }
        }
        return '"' + value.toString().replace(escRE, escFunc) + '"';
      };
    })()
  };
}
```